# Highlight a textbox when there is no input

Tags: c#, windows, forms, textbox

I would like to highlight a textbox when there's no input, here is my sample code

```
if (textBox2.Text == "")
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Please put your password");
                        textBox2.Focus();
                    }
```

I want to highlight it as it like glows, but it only set the Ibeam cursor unto the textbox, please help me, thanks in advance :)

Comment: You'll have to change one or more colors as @Habib points out. An alternate suggestion is to look into using an `ErrorProvider` (but it won't make things glow)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the [background color](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.backcolor.aspx) of the TextBox.

```
textBox2.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using **Winforms** error provider:

```
if (textBox2.Text == "")
{
 errorProvider1.SetError(textBox2, "Please put your password");
 textBox2.BackColor = Color.Red; //to add high light
}
```

See : [C# ErrorProvider](http://www.dotnetperls.com/errorprovider)

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Try this;

```
if (textBox1.Text == "")
{
    MessageBox.Show("Please put your password");
    textBox1.Focus();               
    textBox1.BorderThickness = new Thickness(2, 2, 2, 2);
    textBox1.BorderBrush = Brushes.Red;
    textBox1.Background = Brushes.Beige;                    
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to Add these lines to the CSS:-

```
 .glow:focus {
    border-color: #6EA2DE;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #6EA2DE;
}
```

and in your form you can add a `CssClass` attribute:-

```
<asp:TextBox id="textBox2" CssClass="glow" runat="server"/>
```

Comment: I am not the downvoter, but probably your answer got downvoted because the question was about WinForms, not ASP.Net

Answer (score -1):

You need to set the css border properties on focus of the textbox. Something like this:

## textbox2:focus{

border-color: **whatever color you want**;

}

You can set whatever css properties you in this way.